# The indeterminacy of 0/0 and vacuous truth?

Tags: logic, indeterminate-forms

Today, my roommate and I picked up our friend from the airport. We were supposed to pick him up yesterday, but he missed his flight. We joked that he misses flights a lot, and that only catches 70% of his flights.

I have never missed a flight, so I said "I have made 100% of my flights." My roommate has never flown/booked before. So I said "you've caught all of your flights too, so I guess you catch 100% of your flights. Of course, you've also missed all of your flights, so you catch 0% of your flights."

I can assign any percent of flight success to my roommate because he has had no scheduled flights. It is vacuously true. In a sense, because of the fact that any assigned percent is vacuously true, his percent rate is "indeterminant."

Similarly, if one were to calculate his success rate percent using simple arithmetic, with $s$ meaning "caught flights" and $f$ meaning "scheduled flights", we would have $100 \frac{s}{f} = 100 \frac{0}{0}$, - indeterminant.

Is this a reasonable demonstration of how the two ideas, vacuous truth and indeterminant form, agree with one another in their application? Are there any more profound connections?

Comment: A bit of mathematical lore is that "anything you say about the empty set is true".  So you can as easily say that your non-aviational friend misses  all  of his flights as well as you could that he makes all of them.  I don't myself feel that this sort of indeterminancy is a "vacuous truth", since all statements with _any_ chosen percentage are "equally true". [In a sense, there is no information content among the set of statements, since there is no way to tell which is correct, or if any of them are.    (continued)

Comment: If you're familiar with the "Library of Babel", it has next to no information content for a similar reason.]   My understanding is that a "vacuous" truth is a true statement that carries no implications beyond its own expression (a contemporary [meme] example might be "Longcat is looonng").

Comment: Yes, I can say that he misses all of his flights (that's what I said in the question). This is a vacuous truth. It's not correct that "anything you say about the empty set is true" (immediate counter example, the empty set has cardinality 1). Anything you say about the MEMBERS of the empty set is true, and it's precisely because any such statement is a vacuous truth.

Comment: I think we are disagreeing on what constitutes "vacuity" in this situation.  As I say, my understanding is that a statement such as " $  \ 1 = 1 \ $ " is vacuous because, while it is certainly true, it tells us about pretty much nothing beyond that.  On the other hand, to _state_ a value for an indeterminate expression such as $ \ \frac{0}{0} \ $ is not a vacuous "truth" because there is no way to _resolve_ a meaning for it.  But perhaps your question would be better answered by a _genuine_ logician here, rather than myself...

Comment: A vacuous truth in common mathematical usage, and how I am using it here, is an just implication with a false hypothesis. Any statement of the members of the empty set are vacuous truths because we can write it as "if a is in the empty set, then a is even". https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Vacuous_Truth

Comment: OK, I see I've had a piece of terminology explained incorrectly to me...  [Plainly, I thought tautologies were "vacuous".]  Having looked up the term, I guess that's what you're dealing with in statements of "values" for indeterminate forms.  Whether that has any deeper implications would be something someone else might be better able to remark upon.

Comment: I have enjoyed 100% of all bacon that I have ever eaten. I have also enjoyed 99% of all bacon that I have ever eaten. (As you might have guessed, I've never had any bacon. Am Yisrael Chai.)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner - In what sense  "anything you say about the empty set is true" ? $\exists x (x \in \emptyset)$ is plainly *false*.

Comment: Your comment about *vacuous truth* is correct : the description is usually used for a conditional with *false* antecedent. What is not clear is how this def apply to the "indeterminate" %_failure=missed_flight/total_flight calculated when total_flight=0, and thus : %-failure=$0/0$ ...

Comment: The definition of vacuous truth does not /apply/ to 0/0, but analyzing the idea of a percentage of the members of an empty set with some property using arithmetic and analyzing the idea of a percentage of the members of an empty set with some property with logic and the notion of vacuous truth /agree with one another/. This leads me to believe in a /relationship/ between vacuous truth and indeterminant forms. I did not say that "indeterminant forms are a vacuous truth."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $\forall x\in\emptyset,P(x)$ is true no matter what $P(x)$ is. That's what he meant.

Comment: That's why $\emptyset$ is bounded, open, closed, connected, compact…

Comment: Yes, but that is obvious. RR's misunderstanding was not recognizing these as vacuous truths.

Comment: Um, maybe not connected. Apparently people aren't so sure about that one.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to "handle" indeterminate operations like $0/0$ with the logical "machinery", I think that the theory of [Definite descriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description) - due to B.Russell - is more appropriate than the "model" of conditionals with *false* antecedent.

In a nutshell, Russell's analysis consider a *denoting phrase* in the form of "the $X$" where $X$ is e.g. a singular common noun.

> The definite description is *proper* if $X$ applies to a unique individual or object. For example: "the first person in space" and "the 42nd President of the United States of America", are proper. The definite descriptions "the person in space" and "the Senator from Ohio" are *improper* because the noun phrase $X$ applies to more than one thing, and the definite descriptions "the first man on Mars" and "the Senator from Washington D.C." are improper because $X$ applies to nothing.

Thus, we can say that "the result of the operation $0/0$" is an *improper* definite description, because the operation $0/0$ lacks of a result.

If so, we can handle a statement referring to this description in the way proposed by Russell :

> "The present King of France is bald" says that some $x$ is such that $x$ is currently King of France, and that any $y$ is currently King of France only if $y = x$, and that $x$ is bald:
>
> > $∃x[PKoF(x) \land ∀y[PKoF(y) \to y=x] \land B(x)]$
>
> This is false, since it is not the case that some $x$ is currently King of France.

In the same way, we can try to formalize :

> "You catched 100% of your flights"

as follows, where $PoFC_Y$ stands for "Your roommate Percentage of Flights Catched" :

> $∃x[PoFC_Y(x) \land ∀y[PoFC_Y(y) \to y=x] \land PoFC_Y(x)=100]$

and again it is false because, due to the fact that your roommate has never flown, the *term* $PoFC_Y(x)$ has no denotation (because : the operation $0/0$ is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

When I have seen percentages counted in practice (like win percentages in video games) counted as 0 if there is no data to calculate. So I think if we were to make a function that would calculate the percentage it would be something like: $$p = \begin{cases} 100 \frac{s}{f}, &f\neq 0 \\ 0, &f=0\end{cases}$$

That way there is no ambiguity and I am sure that $f \neq 0$ in the formula you provided. :)

Comment: I'm not really concerned with the use of percentages in practice/statistics.

Comment: @JonathanHebert I just wanted to demonstrate the point that it depends on the use case whether you want it to be 0 or 100.